# Python Pandas: Read specific columns from cdv, then reorder

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv which I need to manipulated and write back.
I only want specific columns (with header) and re-order them.

I use:

```
fields = ['Ticket Number', 'Created', 'Closed', 'CustomerID', 'Customer Realname']
    df = pd.read_csv('args.inname', sep=',', skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields, columns='Created', 'Ticket Number', 'Customer Realname', 'CustomerID', 'Closed')
    df = df.rename(columns={'Ticket Number': 'CaseNumber', 'Created': 'CreationDate', 'Closed': 'ClosedDate', 'CustomerID': 'EndCustomerEmail', 'Customer Realname': 'EndCustomerName'})
```

but it throws a

> SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

right after the second line after I expanded it with "column=" to re-order immediately after reading

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here but can't find it.

Comment: parameter `columns` should be named as `names` and it expects a list: `names=['Created', 'Ticket Number', 'Customer Realname', 'CustomerID', 'Closed']`

Comment: @MaxU tried that as well but get Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'

Comment: I've edited my prev. post - please check...

Comment: @f0rd42, Since you are already selecting the subset of columns via `usecols`, you don't need `names` arg here.

Comment: @NickilMaveli, this way OP may set missing column names and select interesting ones in one step. But he would have to specify `header=None` in this case, so i'm bit confused...

Comment: I need to read specific columns, change order and rename hence need names ( I guess)

Comment: @f0rd42, does your CSV file have column names (headers)?

Comment: @MaxU yes, it does

Comment: f0rd42, in this case read a comment from @NickilMaveli - you don't need `names` parameter as you already have headers (column names)...

Comment: @MaxU OK, but how do I change the order of the columns? The order in the input file if different to whats needed in the output file. Or shall I change the order only when writing the output file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
# specify your columns in the order you want to have it in the ouptut file
fields = ['Ticket Number', 'Created', 'Closed', 'CustomerID', 'Customer Realname']

df = pd.read_csv('args.inname', sep=',', skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields)[fields]

df = df.rename(columns={'Ticket Number': 'CaseNumber', 'Created': 'CreationDate', 'Closed': 'ClosedDate', 'CustomerID': 'EndCustomerEmail', 'Customer Realname': 'EndCustomerName'})
```

Comment: Tried that already (specifying the order in "fields =", but the order is this the original file order, so that only selects the columns but takes the order from the original input file

Comment: @f0rd42, pay attention at `[fields]` in `pd.read_csv(...)[fields]`

Comment: I have date columns read with pandas in the format: YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss but only need YYYY-MM-DD

What is the best and easiest way to trip out the hh:mm:ss in all rows?

Comment: @f0rd42, you can try the following: `df['date_col_name'] = df['date_col_name'].dt.date` - it should work if it's of the `datetime` dtype

Comment: df.dtypes show me it's an "object" type, although I tried reading the csv with parse_dates=True

Comment: `parse_dates=True` works only if your date column is an index column, otherwise you should do it this way: `parse_dates=['date_column_name']`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124721/discussion-between-f0rd42-and-maxu).